# C++ SFML Photo presentation

Tags: c++, sfml

I've installed SFML on my VS2015. I know how to display sprite. Problem occured when I wanted to display another images in the same program.

My goal is to write program which samples without replacement numbers from specified range, shows result on the screen (with few seconds' breaks beetween each) then saves result in txt file. I've done this stage. I only want to display images during sampling. Another specified image for every chosen number.

I don't need code to copy-paste. I just want to get any advice. Which methods available in SFML could help me?

Comment: What do you mean "samples without replacement numbers from specified range"? Post some code on what you have, and a particular problem you are running into. Otherwise, please reiterate on input, calculations, and output your program is supposed to handle.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare a sprite
(  `sf::Sprite sprite`  )
and a texture (  `sf::Texture texture`  ). The, simply load the texture from a file( one of your images ) (  `texture.loadFromFile( "img.png"`) and set the sprite's texture(`sprite.setTexture( texture )`). Now, if you draw the sprite on the screen you should see your full image. I'm 100% sure it works on Windows 10 ,but i don't know if it works on Mac OS or Linux.